# Append html content for each item in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a plugin and need to load the preset and fill out a form with this data. While trying to write the code as short as possible and to my knowledge, I ended up with creating a "template" variable as this:

```
var Fields =  
    '<div class="Container">' +
    '<div class="Fields">' +
    '<input type="text" name="Title" placeholder="Title" />' +
    '<input type="text" name="Address" placeholder="Address" />' +
    '<input type="text" name="Latitude" placeholder="Latitude" />' +
    '<input type="text" name="Longitude" placeholder="Longitude" />' +
    '<input type="text" name="Description" placeholder="Description" />' +
    '<input type="text" name="URL" placeholder="URL" />' +
    '<div class="Image"></div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';
```

And append it like so:

```
$('.results').append($(Fields))
         .find('.Title').text(temp[0]).end()
         .find('input[name="Title"]').val(temp[0]).end()
         .find('input[name="Address"]').val(temp[1]).end()
         .find('input[name="Latitude"]').val(temp[2]).end()
         .find('input[name="Longitude"]').val(temp[3]).end()
         .find('input[name="Description"]').val(temp[4]).end()
         .find('input[name="URL"]').val(temp[5]).end()
         .find('.Image')
         .addClass('added-image')
         .append('<img src="' + temp[6] + '" />').end();
```

The problem I'm facing is that all the data (except the image), is the same. When I `console.log` it shows two sets of data, but still title and so on is the same. Here is my entire function for setting preset:

```
function preset() {
        var str = 'Stackoverflow&%1600 Penn&%10.2342342&%2.2532452&%Need help with this&%http://www.stackoverflow.com&%http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Hausziege_04.jpg;Google&%Silicon Valley 1&%80.435234523&%14.0065592&%This is Google&%http://www.google.com&%http://resources.news.com.au/files/2012/01/13/1226243/386315-harp-seal-1.jpg;',
            arr = {},
            temp = {},
            Fields =  
'<div class="Container">' +
'<div class="Fields">' +
'<input type="text" name="Title" placeholder="Title" />' +
'<input type="text" name="Address" placeholder="Address" />' +
'<input type="text" name="Latitude" placeholder="Latitude" />' +
'<input type="text" name="Longitude" placeholder="Longitude" />' +
'<input type="text" name="Description" placeholder="Description" />' +
'<input type="text" name="URL" placeholder="URL" />' +
'<div class="Image"></div>' +
'</div>' +
'</div>';
        arr = str.split(";");
        $.each(arr,function(i,val){
            temp = arr[i].split("&%");
            if(temp.length >= 2) {
                if(temp[6] !== 'undefined') {
                    $('.results').append($(Fields))
                        .find('.Title').text(temp[0]).end()
                        .find('input[name="Title"]').val(temp[0]).end()
                        .find('input[name="Address"]').val(temp[1]).end()
                        .find('input[name="Latitude"]').val(temp[2]).end()
                        .find('input[name="Longitude"]').val(temp[3]).end()
                        .find('input[name="Description"]').val(temp[4]).end()
                        .find('input[name="URL"]').val(temp[5]).end()
                        .find('.Image')
                        .addClass('added-image')
                        .append('<img src="' + temp[6] + '" />').end();
                } else {
                    $('.results').append($(Fields))
                        .find('.Title').text(temp[0]).end()
                        .find('input[name="Title"]').val(temp[0]).end()
                        .find('input[name="Address"]').val(temp[1]).end()
                        .find('input[name="Latitude"]').val(temp[2]).end()
                        .find('input[name="Longitude"]').val(temp[3]).end()
                        .find('input[name="Description"]').val(temp[4]).end()
                        .find('input[name="URL"]').val(temp[5]).end();
                }
            } else {
                $('.results').append(Fields);
            }
        });
    }
```

I have created a JSFiddle for those who wants to see the result up close, and easier giving me some pointers. http://jsfiddle.net/p7r2n18k/1/

Comment: Oh god your a noob, I like helping noobs. Click collaborate on your jsfiddle and comment the link and I'll help you one on one if you like.

Comment: Thanks! 
http://jsfiddle.net/p7r2n18k/1/#&togetherjs=rLSGws9PVf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `apppend` function appends your fields and returns the element which data was appended to, so it ends up changing all of the fields including older ones.
Seperate the append function from the data update:

```
var fields = $(Fields);
 $('.results').append(fields);
 fields
     .find('.Title').text(temp[0]).end()
     ...
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ecmovhb5/)